# How can I test an app running on a stage environment using Android App Bundles?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

The app has two flavors: stage and prod. Both hit different APIs and have different package ids. We’ve been using App Center to let the QA team make sure everything works as expected, but it does not support AAB, so we’re not able to test the APKs generated from the app bundle. How about creating two applications on Google Play Console? The production flavor will be rolled out from the internal track to the production one, while the stage one will be distributed using just the internal track. The main concern is the apps review process, since both share the same code and have the same look

Comment: _"but it does not support AAB"_ You can generate an APK from an AAB locally using `bundletool`.

Comment: @Michel, you're right, but despite the fact `bundletool` can be used to generate APKs from an AAB, as you mentioned, it's a local solution. We're looking for an alternative which let us distribute the app to the QA team in a more efficient way, taking in mind that the QA team is not working in the same place we are. That’s why we were wondering if we can use the Google Play Console, in the same way we’ve been using App Center. On top of that, Google Play would be in charge of signing each of the APKs generated, so it'd be great if we can share the stage version of the app through its platform

Answer (score 1):

In one of our projects we have 3 different versions of the same app for different environments in Play Store for a similar reason. The store listings are identical, except for the app name (${APP_NAME}, ${APP_NAME} Dev, ${APP_NAME} Test), the package name and the app icon.

I believe, as long as your non-production apps stay in the open and closed testing tracks, the review process will be minimal. And even if you decide to release them to the production track, they should probably be accepted - you can for example see how Chrome has "Chrome Dev", "Chrome Test", "Chrome Canary" all publicly available.

Comment: The package name of an android app have to be unique. How do you handle this limitation in your 3 almost identical apps?

Comment: There are 3 different store apps/listings, which are "identical except for the app name, package name and the app icon". This is basically what the OP has suggested himself, I have just confirmed it. It was possible at the time of answering and it should also be possible now if there haven't been changes in the store's policy.

Comment: I see, in my case I need to distribute the same app with the same package name but different environment configuration. I find it difficult to change package name in all files per environment while these files are still in development. But that's probably another question